# Mammoth usage in Angular/Typescript project

Tags: angular, mammoth

I tried to use mammoth for extracting text from word files in my Angular project. But it won't work. It gives error:

```
path.js:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at 4943 (path.js:25:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 92839 (docx-reader.js:4:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 88933 (index.js:3:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 27345 (taskrolecreator.component.html:71:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 44547 (comments.component.html:58:133)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
```

The error doesn't appear when I remove the following method. This method is not even executed cause the error occurs at launch of the page.

```
    mammoth.extractRawText(file)
    .then(result => {
      const html = result.value;
      const messages = result.messages;
    })
```

I installed it and imported in my component:

```
import * as mammoth from 'mammoth';
```

There is similar question but without an answer.